# Flutter DeepLink getting Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent error

Tags: android, flutter, dart

After installing `uni_links` library i implemented this code as follow

`AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
    <!-- -->

    <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
        <data android:pathPrefix="/links/" />
        <data android:host="deeplink.sample.com" />
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

flutter `SplashScreen` screen:

```dart
class _SplashScreenWidgetState extends State<SplashScreenWidget> {
  StreamSubscription? _sub;

  @override
  void initState() {
    initUniLinks();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(),
    );
  }

  Future<void> initUniLinks() async {
    _sub = linkStream.listen((String? link) {
      if (link != null) {
        print('Listener is working');
        final uri = Uri.parse(link);
        if (uri.queryParameters['id'] != null) {
          print(uri.queryParameters['id'].toString());
        }
      }
    });
  }
}
```

and now as i don't have website to test link i'm trying to use `adb` command, and here command is:

```
adb shell 'am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "unilinks://deeplink.sample.com"'
```

but i get this error:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=unilinks://deeplink.hazaranica.com }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=unilinks://deeplink.sample.com flg=0x10000000 }
```

Comment: hey buddy, able to resolve this issue??

Comment: @Zionnite no :(

Comment: just solve it ~adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://deeplink.sample.com"~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "https://deeplink.sample.com"

Comment: The primary issue revolves around launching the app from the website. Could you assist me in resolving this matter?

Comment: can you verify your assetlinks.json via this website https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator

Comment: by the way, have you been able to lauch the app via the command i gave above??

Comment: yes, it worked, then i should verify assetlinks.json

Comment: good to know that i worked for you, are you building only for android or plus ios?

Comment: we have both of them, android and ios

Comment: have you been able to resolve for ios too?, i can help you with that too if you still have issue there

Comment: not in this time, how can i get your email address?

Comment: do you think there is any penalty for doing that here?

Comment: i'm sure it doesn't any penalty for doing that here, my email is pishguy@gmail.com